# Difference between "открывали", "пооткрывали" and "открыли"

Tags: значения

How are these three sentences different?:

Мы уже **открывали** это окно несколько раз.

Мы уже **пооткрывали** это окно несколько раз.

Мы уже **открыли** это окно несколько раз.

Any slight differences in meaning?

Comment: "Мы уже пооткрывали это окно несколько раз." sounds strange, it's a wrong sentence. `Пооткрывали` means 'opened them all', you can use that verb only when speaking about many objects, "Мы уже пооткрывали эти окна" would be OK, but "несколько раз" doesn't go here.

Comment: @YellowSky Not exactly. Besides different objects that may mean different subjects. That is "I opened it (and then closed) then he opened it etc."

Comment: @user4419802 - По очереди? ))

Comment: @YellowSky - (1) Consider this situation: a film director is rehearsing a scene with actors on set and is telling them what to do: "Пока хозяин квартиры говорит по телефону, вы двое вначале подойдите к столу, постучите по нему несколько раз, потом подойдите к этому окну и приоткройте его - оно от сквозняка само закроется, так что вы пооткрывайте его несколько раз словно вам нечего делать - и только потом уже подходите к двери. Хозяин к этому времени уже должен будет прекратить разговор". Then they start rehearsing and ->

Comment: @YellowSky - (2) something goes wrong. Director shouts: "Почему вы так быстро подошли к двери? Я же сказал вам вначале подойти к окну и пооткрывать его несколько раз!" Actors defend themselves: "Так мы уже пооткрывали его, просто хозяин слишком долго говорил по телефону"

Comment: OK, using пооткрывать in that very situation sounds plausible, still that's a very specific situation, открывали in "Так мы уже открывали его, просто хозяин слишком долго говорил по телефону" would be more natural. The momentary action imperfective verbs with the по- prefix cannot usually be applied to a single object, one cannot say "*мы его поубивали", "*мы окно поразбивали", etc.

Comment: @YellowSky - "**The momentary action imperfective verbs with the по- prefix cannot usually be applied to a single object**" - I am quite confused here. What about "Я его уже пять раз сегодня повстречал"?

Comment: "Повстречал" is a perfective verb, not imperfective.

Comment: @YellowSky - "**"Повстречал" is a perfective verb, not imperfective**" - Hmm... but aren't "поубивал" and "поразбивал" perfective, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мы уже открывали это окно несколько раз.

This one means that we have opened the window several times, but each time someone or something has closed it. Also, it implies that we refuse to open the window once more, or at least we think that it is impractical or pointless. For example, consider the following situation: mother enters children's playroom, and sees the window is wide open (I've replaced "открывали" with "закрывали", but the point remains the same).

```
-- Ах, какой тут сквозняк! Дети, ну-ка быстро закройте окно!
-- Мы его уже закрывали несколько раз! Там шпингалет сломался...
-- Тогда бегом одеваться, а то еще простудитесь!
```

You can also use this word with other meanings, like in "Мы несколько раз открывали на этой улице магазин, но шпана постоянно выбивала стекла и распугивала покупателей". It has the same connotation of a completed action which does not achieved its goal. Does it makes sense?

> Мы уже открыли это окно несколько раз.

This one is definitely incorrect in this particular context. You can't open the already opened window. I guess it *might* be correct in some very special case, something along these lines: "Мы открыли магазин, но на открытие пришло мало людей, так что мы открыли его еще раз", but it still has somewhat ironic sense to it. In general, this sentence is incorrect.

> Мы уже пооткрывали это окно несколько раз.

Thise one sounds kind of colloquial and even childish. The example in the comments to the YellowSky's post perfectly demonstrates the context in which in can be used. Or, continuing with our example, mom could ask the children why the windows is broken:

```
-- Так, а что со шпингалетом случилось?
-- Ну, мы пооткрывали окно... Вот он и сломался.
```

It's worth noticing that the same verb used with a plural form of the same word gives completely different meaning to the phrase. For example, if instead of a mom we'd have an old grumbling grandma, she could say: "Пооткрывали тут окон! Весь дом продуло!", or even "Понаоткрывали тут окон!". Here, she complains about the fact that the windows are open and thus it's cold (depending on the level of grumbliness, it could or could not imply that there is actually more than one window). Also, note that you can't "пооткрывать магазин", but you can "пооткрывать магазинов по всей улице".

Answer (score 0):

В квартире очень душно. Мы уже несколько раз открывали окно, чтобы её проветрить. Мы пооткрывали все окна в квартире, чтобы её проветрить.
 "Мы уже пооткрывали это окно несколько раз" вы сказать не можете, это неграмотно. Для выражения "Мы уже открыли это окно несколько раз" очень сложно найти реальный пример использования. Так не говорят.

The apartment is very stuffy. We have several times opened the window to ventilate. We opened all the Windows in the apartment to be ventilated.
"Мы уже пооткрывали это окно несколько раз," you can't tell, it's illiterate. For the expression "Мы уже открыли окно несколько раз," it is very difficult to find a real use-case. You don't say. Правильный, используемый вариант "Мы уже открывали окно несколько раз."

Comment: **Для выражения "Мы уже открыли это окно несколько раз" очень сложно найти реальный пример использования** - Please, check my comments in reply to YellowSky above.

Comment: "Почему вы так быстро подошли к двери Я же сказал вам вначале подойти к окну и пооткрывать его несколько раз!" В данном случае "открыть его несколько раз", но не "пооткрывать его несколько раз".

Comment: **В данном случае "открыть его несколько раз", но не "пооткрывать его несколько раз"** - Why not?! In that situation I would definitely say that way.

Comment: "Пока хозяин квартиры говорит по телефону, вы двое вначале подойдите к столу, постучите по нему несколько раз, потом подойдите к этому окну и приоткройте его - оно от сквозняка само закроется, так что вы пооткрывайте его, словно вам нечего делать - и только потом уже подходите к двери." "Пооткрывайте его" без "несколько раз" или "откройте его несколько раз".

Comment: Полежу ни диване, поплюю в потолок ( "поплюю  в потолок несколько раз" - неграмотно; грамотно - "плюну в потолок несколько раз").

Comment: "Пооткрывайте его несколько раз" or "Пооткрывайте его несколько раз подряд" sounds pretty much fine to me. Especially in that situation. The film director uses the prefix "по-" to emphasize that that action must be performed without any special reason - just to "kill time" before the telephone conversation is over. In this case "**по**открывайте окно" echoes "**по**играйте с окном от нечего делать". "Откройте его несколько раз" wouldn't convey that meaning. Sure, there is some redundancy like in "взлетать вверх", "спускаться вниз", but that's not a big crime.

Comment: Просто "пооткрывайте его" без "несколько раз подряд". Или "откройте его несколько раз подряд." Таков русский язык, не нам его переделывать.:)

Comment: "**Таков русский язык, не нам его переделывать**" - Why on earth "Пооткрывайте его несколько раз подряд" is not Russian?! Sounds quite Russian to me. Just like "взлетать вверх" or "спускаться вниз".

Comment: Поплюю от безделья в потолок, пооткрываю-позакрываю окно. Если добавить "несколько раз" будет плохой русский язык. А "плюну несколько раз в потолок и открою-закрою несколько раз окно" - хороший, правильный русский язык.

Comment: Is "спускаться вниз" bad Russian? Looks like the matter of taste to me.

Comment: "Спускаться вниз" это литературное, нормативное выражение. Оно не режет слух носителю языка. "Пооткрывай-позакрывай окно" - выражение редкое, но тоже не режет слух носителю языка. А "пооткрывай-позакрывай окно несколько раз" - слух режет. "Открой-закрой окно несколько раз" - слух не режет.

Comment: "Пооткрывай несколько раз окно" то же, что "полежи, поплюй несколько раз в потолок ". Bad Russian. Если Вы не чувствуете здесь неправильность, Вам это не режет слух, тогда наша дискуссия бессмысленна.

Comment: "**Вам это не режет слух, тогда наша дискуссия бессмысленна**" - Quite on the contrary. If it did grate on my ear, _then_ our debate would be meaningless as in that case we would completely agree with each other.

Comment: Приставка ПО обозначает действие в течение определенного времени, глагол с такой приставкой не может обозначать количество действий.

Answer (score 0):

#1

> Мы уже открывали это окно несколько раз.

We were opening the window many times. (but they not necessarily managed to)

#3

> Мы уже открыли это окно несколько раз.

Same, but they managed to open it.

#2 is incorrect.

> Мы уже пооткрывали это окно несколько раз.

Correct way of using this form:

> [Было так душно, что] Мы пооткрывали все окна.
>
> Сквозняк закрывал окно, мы пооткрывали его несколько раз, а потом бросили.

(The draught kept closing the window. So we were opening it for a while, then gave up.)

Still, one could occasionally use #2 in speech, meaning this but changing the sentence structure on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

> Мы уже открывали это окно несколько раз.

Here it means that you had opened the window several times. Without несколько раз it may mean you opened it once, but now it is closed (or at least it became closed after you opened it, even if now it is opened).

> Мы уже пооткрывали это окно несколько раз.

You had opened the window several times over a continuous time period, but now you stopped this activity and possibly do not want to repeat. Несколько раз is redunant here, пооткрывали implyes it was your activity over some time period to open the window (so you did it several times).

> Мы уже открыли это окно несколько раз.

Impossible unless the window permits being opened more than once without closing it. This can be OK in other context when you can open something several times without closing it:

> Закон сохранения импульса открыли несколько раз.

You can also say

> Закон сохранения импульса открывали несколько раз.

The later implyes you do not know all cases where it was discovered, you just say it was several times. Maybe some cases are forgotten and lost to history. The former implyes you know all the instances well and there are a few of them, all of them are remembered till now, even if they were unknown to each other's researchers at the time when they were doing the discoveries.